# How to send HTTP request using flow-framework

Tags: java, flow-framework

I´m currentliy working in a project. I need to stablish conection with a API-REST (backend) that is built with Java.

The point is that as frontend, I have to use flow-framework. I know how to use Angular als frontend to send http request to backends with Laravel, Symfony or NodeJs..

I habe googled but I don´t find a clear example of how to do it..:((

Maybe could you help me..

Thanks a lot in advance..

Greetings :))

Comment: Hey @serenimus, welcome to SO. I would like to let you know that this is not how you are supposed to ask for help here. What you can do instead is show the community what you've tried (show some code) and where you're stuck and then the community might be able to help you with what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Hey!, thanks for your advice..I´ll try to write some code...:))